# Getting an 'ambiguous redirect' error

Tags: linux, unix

I'm really new to this and I'm not understanding why it's an 'ambiguous redirect'. I have the text file "employee_data". It is specifically saying it on line 29.

[Image of script](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7SPQ3.png)

Comment: Please paste the text of the script (or whatever it is you're running) into your question.  Also, paste the error messages.  To get the code and the output presented 'properly', enter them in the text box (ignore the preview for the time being), and get the material looking correct. Make sure there are no tabs in the material. Then select it and use the **`{}`** button above the edit box to indent the material 4 spaces.  It will be presented as code (constant width font, greyed background).  Now check the preview to ensure it looks as you expect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you actually want the literal file name employee_data?

Then write `>> employee_data` not `>> $employee_data`

If you mean something else, please clarify.

Comment: Thank you, I should of been more specific I wanted it to add to the file. which it does now thanks!